# Could not write JSON: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException

Tags: java, spring, jackson

My application seems to work ok if I have 2 records or less in my database, but if I add more data then I got this warning in maven and error in the response:

```
2019-03-02 21:36:44.642  WARN 14734 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[2])]
```

It's actually quite strange, I receive the data and I'm able to output it in a string for instance, but if I return the list then crashes in execution.

My code:

```
package com.awesome2048.score;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class ScoreController {

    @Autowired
    ScoreRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("/scores")
    public List<Score> fetchScores() throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<Score> scores = (List<Score>) repository.findAll();
        return scores;
    }

}
```

The entity Score:

```
package com.awesome2048.score;

import javax.persistence.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@JsonSerialize(using = ScoreSerializer.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "scores")
public class Score {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "score", nullable = false)
    private int score;

    @Column(name = "ip", nullable = false)
    private String ip;

    public Score(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public Score() {}

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return this.score;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return this.ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        String endpoint = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=62ee2a10303261af0cf55d6eb2c807c8db5e6fa539fe5ba843c341f4062bfaea&ip= " + this.getIp();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String countryCode = restTemplate.getForObject(endpoint, String.class).split(";")[3];
        return countryCode;
    }
}
```

I also implemented a custom serializer:

```
package com.awesome2048.score;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ScoreSerializer extends StdSerializer<Score> {

    public ScoreSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public ScoreSerializer(Class<Score> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Score score, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("name", score.getName());
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("score", score.getScore());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("countryCode", score.getCountryCode());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide exception stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is your get method:

```
public String getCountryCode() {
 String endpoint = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=62ee2a10303261af0cf55d6eb2c807c8db5e6fa539fe5ba843c341f4062bfaea&ip= " + this.getIp();
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 String countryCode = restTemplate.getForObject(endpoint, String.class).split(";")[3];
 return countryCode;
}
```

You are using [`ipinfodb API`](https://ipinfodb.com/api) which has limitation. Info from their page:

> To remain the stabilities of free service, a rate limit of **2 queries
>   per second** applied to our API servers. Any IP querying the API
>   faster than this rate will temporarily blocked by our firewall. Your
>   IP will permanently banned if your keep hitting the API server by
>   ignoring this rate limit.

`getter` like this is a classical example of [side effect in programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect). You can not invoke other services, write data on disk in `POJO` methods which are designed to `get/set` variable. Instead, try to create batch job which will scan `scores` table and update required information. This implementation should take care about server limitation `2 requests per second`.